# ¿Como solucionar el error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un percance en mi proyecto y es que cada vez que ingreso un dato en una DataGridView me sale ese error en la que carga la form, lo que hace la form donde me marca el error del Object es que tras que el timer cuente 100 junto a una Progress Bar abra la form donde ingreso datos en la DataGrid pero como dije antes al ingresar un dato me genera el error en la form donde carga y esa misma form es con la que inicia Program.cs

```
        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        conteo++;
        Prb.Value++;
        if (conteo == 100)
        { timer1.Enabled = false; }
        if (Prb.Value == 100)
        {
              this.Hide();
            Main2 open = new Main2();
            open.ShowDialog();
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }

    }
```

Comment: en cual linea esta el error?

Comment: lo marca en el ShowDialog